# How to clear the last line in the command window

Tags: matlab

I'm curious about the progress of the running program and I print some information about the current iteration such as:

```
for i = 1:N
    ...
    ...
    msg = sprintf('Processed %d/%d', i, N);
    display(msg)
end
```

I don't want to print the progress on separate lines, instead, I want the last line to replace the previous one. I don't want to use `clc` which clears all the content.

I know that `'\b'` can clear the last character (like backspace) and I can create a function with a for loop which clears the items till the previous new line before the last. But is there a better way to do that? If not, how can I check whether the last character on the command line is a new line or not?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've looked at the problem, a while ago. And I've noticed that the character `\r` (used to erase the last line) works with matlab in command-line (-nodesktop) but not with the graphic mode...

The best solution I found is to do something like that:

```
n=0;
for ...
  ...
  fprintf(repmat('\b',1,n));
  fprintf(msg);
  n=numel(msg);
end
```

Comment: note : this eats your previous text. you should probably save the length of msg every loop, and only `fprintf(repmat('\b', 1, lengthLastMsg));`

Answer (score 19):

[Yair Altman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233829/yair-altman) has [a very nice example on his blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/command-window-text-manipulation/) of how you can use the backspace control-character (`\b`) to do what you want but in an easier way than you were considering. Modifying your code to resemble his example, you could do something like this:

```
reverseStr = '';
for i = 1:N
    ...
    ...
    msg = sprintf('Processed %d/%d', i, N);
    fprintf([reverseStr, msg]);
    reverseStr = repmat(sprintf('\b'), 1, length(msg));
end
```

Comment: + This is a great clear answer gnovice, thank you very much. I'm quite confused but I would better accept Oli's answer for 2 min difference :S

Comment: @İsmailArı: I don't quite understand what you mean by "I'm quite confused but I would better accept Oli's answer for 2 min difference".

Comment: I mean I don't know which to accept when two answers are very similar. This is the first time I meet this issue. Both are very helpful for me. Which one should I accept? 2 min difference is the gap between the answers as I see.

Comment: @İsmailArı: Oh, I see. That's OK. I was worried maybe something in my answer was confusing. Sometimes users post similar answers at the same time, and it's totally up to you to decide how to break the tie. Even though our code is similar, Oli did make the extra mention of the `\r` character, so I understand giving him the check. ;)

Comment: These ain't "useful comments".

Comment: Is there a way to wrap this into a function?

Answer (score 3):

I use 'dispstat' function just for this purpose. It can update the previous output which is a missing function of default 'disp'. Very simple to use. It can be downloaded from here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44673-overwritable-message-outputs-to-commandline-window

***Sample usage:

```
 dispstat('','init'); % One time only initialization
 dispstat(sprintf('Begining the process...'),'keepthis','timestamp');
 for i = 97:100
     dispstat(sprintf('Progress %d%%',i),'timestamp');
     %doing some heavy stuff here
 end
 dispstat('Finished.','keepprev');
```

***Output:

```
11:25:37 Begining the process...
11:25:37 Progress 100%
Finished.
```

All the best

Answer (score 2):

Is this about what you are looking for

```
%# create title
fprintf('processed: %03d',0)
for i=1:10
    %# delete last three digit number and replace with new
    %# loop index
    fprintf('\b\b\b\b %03d',i);

    %# process here
    pause(.5)
end
%# clear line
fprintf('\n');
```

But if your code displays other results this won't work. and you might want to consider using a message box to update progress.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that overwrites the entire previous line relies on the `\r` formatting character,

```
ctrl=0;
while ctrl<5
    fprintf('\rctrl: %i',ctrl);
    ctrl=ctrl+1;
    pause(2); % To highlight overwrite 
end
fprintf('\n'); % Don't forget the newline
```