# How to wrap rewriting a console line into a simple function

Tags: matlab

I have lots of I/O functions in Matlab that write and read pretty big files. I like a clean progress report while they are running and they run often, so naturally I don't want to spam the console. There's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8826116/1333515) here that has an elegant solution to this problem (although it's a shame that Matlab has no builtin function that does this!).

However, this still adds a lot of clutter to my code. If my function exports 5 big things to a single file and I want a customized progress report on all of them, then that's at least 25 lines of extra code that is mostly similar. It would be natural to thus wrap these into a simple function. I tried this, but when it's wrapped within a function, the backslash characters in the reversal string seem to be ignored. Why is this? Below is a simple test case that you can copy-paste.

```
function test()
    %Example formatted string: a single decimal. 
    str='%d ';
    reverseStr='';

    %Rewriting a console line explicitly
    disp('Case 1:');
    for j=1:10
        msg = sprintf(str, j);
        fprintf([reverseStr, msg]);
        reverseStr = repmat(sprintf('\b'), 1, length(msg));
        pause(0.5)
    end
    fprintf('\n');

    %Try doing the same thing wrapped within a function.
    disp('Case 2:');
    for j=1:10
        reportToConsole(str,j)
        pause(0.5)
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end

function reportToConsole(str, varargin)  
    reverseStr='';
    msg = sprintf(str, varargin{:});
    fprintf([reverseStr, msg]);
    reverseStr = repmat(sprintf('\b'), 1, length(msg));
    pause(0.5)
end
```

Running 'test' outputs to:
[image]

**Edit:**
I think I found the problem. It's the fact that `reverseStr` does not get the right length because it depends on the script running several times. Replacing `reportToConsole()` with a simple `fprintf(...); clc;` does not seem to work. Neither does defining the `reverseStr` after printing the message because it immediately gets deleted. Adding a `pause` would be really inelegant because that would slow everything down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're resetting the value of `reverseStr` in every loop iteration for case 2.

Try this function instead:

```
function test()
    str='%d ';
    reverseStr='';
    for j=1:10
        reverseStr = reportToConsole(str,j, reverseStr);
        pause(0.1)
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end

function reverseStr = reportToConsole(str, j, reverseStr)  
    msg = sprintf(str, j);
    fprintf('%s', [reverseStr, msg]);
    reverseStr = repmat(sprintf('\b'), 1, length(msg));
    pause(0.1)
end
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but using the string `'%d %% \n` makes the function remove a character too many each iteration. It should actually display the percentage sign.

Comment: @PatronBernard the issue exists with the loop solution too. It's an issue with your `fprintf` call. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you. I still hope Mathworks will make this a builtin function so we don't need any external variables.