# matlab 'evidence removio': delete last shown command

Tags: matlab

I would like to remove whatever I just typed - and the last shown command - from the matlab console display. Needless to say, this would be ideal for pranksters (but this is of course strictly for academic purposes only). This is as far as I have gotten (based on this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825796/how-to-clear-the-last-line-in-the-command-window)):

```
hist = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory; %get history
last = strjoin(cell(hist(end-2:end)),' '); %convert history to string
fprintf(repmat('\b',1,numel(last))); %replace characters of string with whitespace
```

However I can only access the last *typed* command (through the command history) - not the last *displayed* command (which would be ideal). Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't advise doing this.

The MATLAB CommandWindow contents are stored as a `CmdWinDocument`, which is an extension of the Java `PlainDocument` type, and an interface of the `Document` type. The current window can be accessed using the command:

```
com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.CmdWinDocument.getInstance
```

In theory, you should be able to remove text from the command window using something like:

```
doc = com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.CmdWinDocument.getInstance
endpos = doc.getEndPosition
doc.remove(endpos-10,10)
```

which would, in theory, remove the last 10 character from the document. You may have to call the `removeUpdate` function as well. Obviously problems will be caused by the fact that these commands will be appended to the document during this process. I have **not** tested this, and you're likely to cause problems with internally stored offsets within the `CmdWinDocument` class, so use at your own risk.